# How can I make a table row's background color surpass its text?

Tags: html, css

Setting a table row's background color to grey, you'd get a table row that would look like this

```
+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------+---------------+
|Col1               |        Col2        |          Col3          | Numeric Column|
+------------ ------+--------------------+------------------------+---------------+
```

I want to be able to pad the left and right most texts however to get an effect like this

```
    +----------------+------------------+----------------------+---------------+
    |     Col1       |        Col2      |        Col3          | Numeric Column|
    +----------------+------------------+----------------------+---------------+
```

Is it possible? I want this effect for both rows and headers

Table HTML and CSS Below:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 1rem;
    font-size: 85%;
}

th {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    border: 0;
}

td {
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="content-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Age</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Height</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Stephen Curry</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>1,91</td>
            <td>Akron, OH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Klay Thompson</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>2,01</td>
            <td>Los Angeles, CA</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit:
Found an image by `ueno` on Dribbble that shows the effect I'm trying to achieve. In the image below, you can see that the table rows' background color slightly pass the text whereas on my table (2nd image), it does not. I understand that I can set text-align: center as some people are saying in the comments however I prefer the left align with just a bit of padding.
[image: Vonigo by ueno on Dribbble]

[image]

Comment: It appears that you want to add both padding (space between text and cell) and margin (space between table and parent). Can you add your table HTML and CSS to your post?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Try to do something first, then show us your code so we know how to help you and tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Your markup is like a database layout markup usualy used on SO. There is really no visual idea of your problem. Instead you should post the relevant code, or even better a snippet ...

Comment: My bad! Just edited my post to show what I have so far.

It's working as intended (Spacing between rows) however I can't seem to pad the text

Comment: What doe you mean with `I can't seem to pad the text`?

Comment: i don't get it. bad problem description. please improve your question to make it as understandable as possible.

Comment: `th, td {text-align: center;}`? I'm not sure what the question is. It seemed like you didn't want your second "example", but you asked if it is possible. Try playing with margins, padding, and alignment.

Comment: How about using Bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#striped-rows

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean but here is how you can center the text in the row.

An example plunker :

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 1rem;
    font-size: 85%;
}

th {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    border: 0;
}

tr {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    border: 0;
}

td {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0;
}
.text-center{
  text-align: center;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<table class="content-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
            <th class="text-center"><strong>Age</strong></th>
            <th class="text-center"><strong>Height</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Stephen Curry</td>
            <td class="text-center">27</td>
            <td class="text-center">1,91</td>
            <td>Akron, OH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Klay Thompson</td>
            <td class="text-center">25</td>
            <td class="text-center">2,01</td>
            <td>Los Angeles, CA</td>
        </tr>
        
                <tr>
            <td>Klay Thompson</td>
            <td class="text-center">25</td>
            <td class="text-center">2,01</td>
            <td>Los Angeles, CA</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see i have made an `class` called `.text-center` and attached it to the columns I have understood you want to be centered. You can create same classes for -right and -left alignment. And changed some tags as 
`th` to `tr` in `tbody`. I hope this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you were trying to get but this achieves the effect you have shown in the ueno picture above.

```css
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width:100%;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;

}

td, th {

padding: 12px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}


th {
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
text-align: left;
background-color: white;
color: black;
```

```html
<table class="content-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Age</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Height</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Stephen Curry</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>1,91</td>
            <td>Akron, OH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Klay Thompson</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>2,01</td>
            <td>Los Angeles, CA</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
            <td>Stephen Curry</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>1,91</td>
            <td>Akron, OH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Klay Thompson</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>2,01</td>
            <td>Los Angeles, CA</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```